# Stored procedure return value -1 in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF and I am calling a stored procedure. I get a return value of -1, but when I execute this stored procedure in SQL Server, then the result is correct.

When I use this

```
var Reg_ID = _db.Database.SqlQuery<Registration("SP_RandomNo_Reg").SingleOrDefault();
```

I got the error

> "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'ECommercedbModel.Registration'. A member of the type, 'Name', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'"

Model class:

```
 public partial class Registration
 {
     public int Reg_ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

EShoppingConcrete:

```
 public string mMaxNo_Reg()
 {
     var Reg_ID = _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SP_RandomNo_Reg");
     return Reg_ID.ToString();
 }
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult mMax_No_Rg()
{
    try
    {
        ViewBag.max_ID = _IRegistration.mMaxNo_Reg();
        return Json(ViewBag.max_ID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_RandomNo_Reg] 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        RIGHT('000'+ CAST(ISNULL(MAX(Reg_ID), 0) + 1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + '', 4) AS Reg_ID 
    FROM 
        Registration
END
```

Comment: seems like you are missing '>' sign after the word Registration in your first line of code

Comment: also, remove name from Registration class to make it work.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: this was added mistakenly but I have added in my code @Jawad

Comment: from Registration this a table name if I remove the table name then Reg_id will show error invalid column name "Reg_id" @Jawad

Comment: thanks for information @marc_s can you help me what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: If you still have issues after implementing the above comments I noticed that your class 'Registration' is a partial class.  Make sure you are not including other properties in your class definition by removing 'partial'.

Comment: still the same issue @Mark McWhirter

Answer (score 1):

To execute a stored procedure and return a type string, change statement to read:

```
public string mMaxNo_Reg()
{
     return _db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SP_RandomNo_Reg").Single();
}
```

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft you are correct, sir!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteSqlCommand` is not for returning data, its for DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE. If you need to return data from your SP, then use `FromRawSql`:

```
public string mMaxNo_Reg()
{
     var reg = _db.Registrations.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE SP_RandomNo_Reg");
     return reg.Reg_ID.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't found the FromSqlRaw , can you tell me the assembly name and i am using a repository pattern.

Comment: @zee are you using EF Core?

Comment: No. I am using EF.